# Kendo UI Server paging using spring framework

Tags: spring, kendo-ui

```
<%@taglib prefix="kendo" uri="http://www.kendoui.com/jsp/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="demo" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <%@include file="jspf/meta.jspf" %>
        <!-- title -->
        <title><spring:message code='APPNAME' text='STC' /> - <spring:message code='ASSETS' text='Assets' /></title>
        <!-- kendo ui styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<spring:url value='/assets/kendoui/styles/kendo.common.min.css'/>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<spring:url value='/assets/kendoui/styles/kendo.material.min.css'/>">
        <!-- kendo ui scripts -->   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value='/assets/sm/js/jquery.js'/>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value='/assets/kendoui/js/kendo.all.min.js'/>"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <spring:url value="/secure/assets/list" var="transportReadUrl" />
        <kendo:grid name="grid" selectable="single" pageable="true" groupable="true" sortable="true" filterable="true">
            <kendo:grid-columns>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Name" field="name" />
                <kendo:grid-column title="Quantity" field="quantity" />
                <kendo:grid-column title="Dimensions" field="dimensions" />
            </kendo:grid-columns>
            <kendo:dataSource pageSize="5" serverPaging="true">
                <kendo:dataSource-schema data="assets" total="total">
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                            <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="name" type="string" />
                            <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="quantity" type="number" />
                            <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="dimensions" type="number" />
                        </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
                </kendo:dataSource-schema>
                <kendo:dataSource-transport>
                    <kendo:dataSource-transport-read  contentType="application/json" type="POST" url="${transportReadUrl}"/>
                </kendo:dataSource-transport>
            </kendo:dataSource>
        </kendo:grid>
    </body>
</html>
```

Okey thats my jsp page. On other hand my controller is this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
//public String listAssetsJSON(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize) throws Exception {
public String listAssetsJSON(@RequestBody DataSourceRequest request) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("ttttt "+request.getPage()+" "+request.getPageSize());
```

Datasourcerequest.java as well below for your info

```
public class DataSourceRequest {
    private int page;
    private int pageSize;
    private int take;
    private int skip;
    private HashMap<String, Object> data;
    public DataSourceRequest() {
        data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    public HashMap<String, Object> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }
    public int getTake() {
        return take;
    }
    public int getSkip() {
        return skip;
    }
}
```

I still get page and pagesize as null. and never get it right, why it is not working? Whats the solution, what wrong i have done? what do i need to define more? i followed most tutorials.

I also add setters to datarequest, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You also need this

```
<kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
   function(options){return JSON.stringify(options);}
</kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
```